# Emit token depending on context

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am using antlr 2.7.4 to create a lexer. I am stuck at the following case:

- if Colon (':') is followed by characters from class C1, COLON token should be emitted followed by token C1
- if Colon is followed by Character from character class C2, colon should be taken as part of C2 and token C2 should be emitted.

Assuming Class C1 is {1,2,3} and Class C2 is {A,B,C} then :13 should tokenized as COLON followed by C1. However :AB should be tokenized as C2.

More concretely, I have grammar for a language which has two constructs:

- Identifier : Type  // It has three tokens: IDENT COLON IDENT . Pascall like type annotation
- ::   // this is an identifier. There is a class of character that can be used as identifiers. Colon can be used as identifier provided it is used with other characters of the class

Some examples:

- myvar : Int   // IDENT COLON IDENT
- ::   // IDENT
- :$   // IDENT
- &:& // IDENT

A followup question: Is it possible to check if a certain look ahead character belongs to certain Token class ?
Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

### EDIT

I guess I am the only user of antlrv2. I will be happy to have a solution in antlrv3 and see if I could hack it in antlrv2.

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason to use ANTLR v2, I'd go for v3 instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I *have* to use antlr2.

Comment: You might find out (by the lack of responses) that ANTLR v2 is not used that much anymore. All I can do is recommend you take it up with the powers that be that force you to use this old version and try to convince them to let you use a newer version (assuming that is possible, otherwise, you might be just out of luck).

Comment: will be happy to accept a solution in antlrv3.

Comment: I'll have a closer look at it this evening (@work now) and might propose a v3 solution (if no one else makes a suggestion before then).